# White die on silver platter has to be used?

Tags: thats-pretty-clever

In the game That's So Clever/Ganz Shön Clever the active player can pick up to three dice that he uses and place the remaining dice on the silver platter. The passive players can then pick one die from that silver platter and use it for their own scoring sheet.

The way dice are uses is limited depending on the color of the die, the number of the die and what has already been crossed of on the scoring sheet.

The only color that can always be filled in is orange. Here you just enter the number that is represented on the die in the orange row.

White is a wild die, it can be used to represent any color (in case it is used as blue the value of both dice is added).

If a passive player can not use any of the dice on the silver platter they can use one that is on the active player's scoresheet.

With white being a wild card and orange being able to always be used on the scoresheet (unless it is already full), does a passive player need to use the white die as an orange one if it's on the silver platter and it is the only possibility to add one of the dice from the silver platter to his/hers scoresheet? Or can he/she use one of the dice on the active players scoresheet?

So: do you need to take the white die as an orange one if the white die is on the silver platter and you can not use the other dice (or the white die as any other color) on the silver platter?

Comment: From the title, I thought this was about an incredibly posh boardgame where you had to roll your die onto an actual physical silver platter for it to be legal...

Comment: @PhilipKendall I can see it looks weird when you don't know the game. But it's just a silver platter printed on the inside of the box (https://boardgamegeek.com/image/4544136/s-pretty-clever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a copy of the rules here; [Translation of Rules](https://tesera.ru/images/items/1269156/Ganz_schon_clever.pdf)

The relevant section is the Special Case section rather than the Passive Player section.

> Special Case
> If a passive player can’t use any die from the silver platter, they may use one die from the active player’s pad. It is not possible to voluntarily refuse a die from the silver platter to do this.

In this instance, a passive player with space left on their orange track can use one of the dice on the silver plate, the White one to fill an orange space so cannot use one of the dice from the Active player's pad.

There is a potential loop hole, the rules linked above in the passive player section say each passive player **can** choose a dice from the silver tray suggesting it is possible to decide not to take anything at all.

This doesn't appear to be the case based on the original [german rules](https://www.schmidtspiele.de/files/Produkte/4/49340%20-%20Ganz%20sch%C3%B6n%20clever/49340_Ganz_schoen_Clever_DE.pdf) which use the word must, which replicates my experience with the app version of the game.

> Alle passiven Spieler bekommen nun die zur Seite
> gelegten Würfel auf dem Silbertablett serviert. Von diesen Würfeln muss jeder Mitspieler einen Würfel auswählen und auf seinem Spielblatt (inden passenden Farbbereich) eintragen.

> All passive players now get the aside placed dice served on a silver platter. Each player must use one of these dice and enter it on their scoresheet (in enter the appropriate color range).

Comment: Yeah I have the dutch version and that one just says 'every player chooses a die from the platter'. It also says that you can choose a die from the active player if they can not use one from the platter. But that seems to be optional.